# str_to_date error in MySQL (Java)

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, str-to-date

I have the following column value which I am converting and storing in another column

```
Nov 22 2014 00:00:00 AM
```

Now I am using the following query to convert it to Date format and store in another column

```
UPDATE DataNov2014 SET Datee = str_to_date(Date,'%d %b %Y %H:%i:%s');
```

But I am getting the following exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect datetime
>   value: 'Nov  22 2014 00:00:00 AM' for function str_to_date

Is there any mistake in my query/date format ??

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Is the Hour:min:sec is in 24 hour format or 12 hour format ?

Comment: SO is the issue in mysql `00:00:00 AM` is invalid. You can have `00:00:00 AM` only in 24 hour format not in 12 hours format. So it needs to be in 24 hour format and the str_to_date should be as `str_to_date(Date,'%b %d %Y %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: %r Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)....
This is the format of a 12 hr time in mysql @AbhikChakraborty, right ?

Comment: Yes its allowed but you can not have `00:00:00` its invalid in 12 hour format it has to be `12:00:00 AM`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that silly error. Now my Time is "Nov
 22 2014 00:00:00" and Update query says "STR_TO_DATE(Date,'%d %b %Y %T')". Why this is still giving the same exception ?

Comment: I think it should be `str_to_date(Date,'%b %d %Y %T')`, you has `%d %b ...`

Answer (score 0):

tyr this

```
UPDATE DataNov2014 SET Date= to_char(Date,'mon dd yyyy mm:ss:hh');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and a [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) bind parameter. Also, you can use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Putting it all together, something like

```
String sql = "UPDATE DataNov2014 SET Datee = ?";
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    Date theDate = sdf.parse("11-22-2014 00:00:00");
    ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(theDate.getTime()));
    int count = ps.executeUpdate();
    if (count > 0) {
        System.out.printf("Query updated %d rows.%n", count);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Query didn't update any rows");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have never used prepared statement, are you sure that this will solve my problem, because the exception I am getting is in the source date format !

Comment: @Gagan93 I would recommend you start using prepared statements. Also, I am positive that if you have a Java `Date` Object using `setDate()` will help (you aren't converting from a `String` to a `Date`, and the JDBC driver knows how to store `Date`(s)).

Answer (score 0):

Assumes your field `Datee` datatype is `Datetime`

> UPDATE DataNov2014 SET Datee = str_to_date('Nov 22 2014 00:00:00 AM','%M %d %Y %H:%i:%s');